# Grails hasMany relationship query

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

I have a many-to-many relationship but can't work out how to get the results I need.

```
Tutor {
    String name
    hasMany = [locations:Location]
}
Location {
    String name
    hasMany = [tutors:Tutor]
    belongsTo = Tutor
}
```

The database looks correct with a tutor, location and tutor_location(tutor.id,location.id) table.

How can I find all the locations associated with a tutor?

I've tried create criteria but doesnt work. `Location.listAllByTutor(tutorid)` doesn't work either.

Comment: Unless I am missing something that you didn't state in the question but loading an instance of the tutor should give you access to the locations collection for that Tutor. E.g. myTutorInstance.locations

Comment: I assume you do have `static` before `hasMany` and `belongsTo`, yes?

Answer (score 1):

First find your `Tutor`:

```
def tutor = Tutor.get(1)
```

Then access the `locations`:

```
def locations = tutor.locations
```

This defaults to lazy initialization, so the second query will execute when you access the `locations` list.